# Как копировать ключевые слова в DLE?

Tags: dle

Помогите понять можно ли как-нибудь скопировать сразу несколько ключевых слов и чтобы они не сливались в одно поле в движке dle?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(Да, копирование по одному слову работает, но иногда нужно вставить очень много тегов одновременно)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ. Поможет разделитель между тегами в виде запятой. И сразу все вставляется как нужно